# how to define the partitioned by type with smallrye-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye

I have a simple quarkus project that create topic "databases" and send list of databases to it.

How can I control the partitions?

I want to have different partition per each DatabaseID so all the messages with same Id will go to the same partition.

here is my application.properties:

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

mp.messaging.outgoing.databases.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.databases.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.databases.value.serializer=com.secupi.dbmanager.model.DatabaseSerializer
quarkus.class-loading.removed-resources."org.slf4j\:slf4j-api"=org.slf4j.Logger.class
```

and my code

```
@Outgoing("databases")
public <T> Multi<Record<String, Database>> generate() {
                Collection<Database> dbs = databaseDao.getAll(new FilterParams());
            return Multi.createFrom().items(dbs.stream().map(db -> Record.of(db.getName(), db)));                   
}
```

By default as I see the topic has been created with 100 partitions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions in your topic depends on how you are creating it. If it is auto-created the default number of partitions is configured on Kafka broker config. IF you are in dev-mode using Quarkus devservices you can configure it to create topic-partitions for you : https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#configuring-kafka-topics

If the topic is already created with 100 partitions, all you need to do is produce Kafka records with consistent keys. In the snippet you've sent if you create `Record.of` with database ID as your key the default partitioner will assign it to a unique partition every time.